# How to use same page template if post status other than 'publish'?

Tags: templates, post-status

Quick question about relationship between post status and template.

If non-logged user tried to access a page(or a post) which status is `private` or `draft` (or anything other than `publish`), how do I still use the same page template?

Usually non-logged user is redirected to 404.php (if not exists index.php).

Then I want to use conditional statement to what content to show.

Comment: Everything is possible. Unfortunately there some important info missing. Please file an [edit] with the following info: 1.) What content do you want to show and where will it be coming from 2.) Will that content be dynamic or static. 3.) How should the 404 be handled